# .NET ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList selecting while typing

Tags: .net, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a ComboBox with a list of names. I don't want to allow new values, so I set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList.

When typing to select a name, it only allows one letter. So if I type "T" it will jump to the first name starting with "T". If I then type "o", it will not jump to the first item starting with "To", but to the first item starting with "o".

Is there a way to change this behaviour? Either with the current DropDownStyle, or with a different one by restricting it to existing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `AutoCompleteSource` to `Items`, then set `AutoCompleteMode`. `SuggestAppend` is probably what you're looking for, but you can play with the others and choose which one you like.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I don't notice any difference between Suggest and SuggestAppend, I guess it doesn't matter when the style is DropDownList.